# LINQ Group By along with percent of list that contains element

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by

Example is probably the easiest way to explain:

```
{1,2,2,3}
```

becomes

```
{
    {1,0.25}
    {2,0.5}
    {3,0.25}
}
```

I'm thinking I'd do the inner pairs using a simple struct. I understand using GroupBy and everything, but is there a way to create a new list like this in one big LINQ statement?

another example:

```
{'a','g','a','a','f'}
```

becomes

```
{
    {'a',0.6}
    {'g',0.2}
    {'f',0.2}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want something like this

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void T()
    {
        var mySet = new List<string> { "a", "b", "a" };
        var set = from i in mySet
                  group i by i into g
                  select new { Item = g.Key, Percentage = ((double)g.Count()) / mySet.Count() };

        Assert.AreEqual(2, set.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual("a", set.First().Item);
        Assert.AreEqual(2.0/3, set.First().Percentage);
    }
```

Comment: The pseudo-code told me enough haha, but thanks regardless. I'll accept in a minute.

Comment: @wilson awesome, i can only remember so much without my lovely compilers help ;)